# What are some possible solutions to resolve the LNK1104 error in my program?

Tags: c++, unit-testing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYss2.png)I'm doing unit testing and I get an error
(unit test error file code Severity Code Description Project File String Suppression Status
Error LNK1104 unable to open file "process.obj" unit-test-project   C:\Users\Vladimir\source\repos\ConsoleApplication35\unit-test-project\LINK  1
)
unit-test-project.cpp:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "../ConsoleApplication35/processing.h"
#include "../ConsoleApplication35/book_subscription.h"
#include "../ConsoleApplication35/file_reader.h"
#include "CppUnitTest.h"
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;

namespace unittestproject
{
    TEST_CLASS(unittestproject)
    {
    public:
        TEST_METHOD(TestCalculateAverageWindSpeedInMonth)
        {
            // Создаем вектор данных о ветре
            vector<WindInfo> data = {
                { 1, 1, "West", 6.2 },
                { 2, 1, "NorthWest", 4.5 },
                { 3, 1, "North", 3.8 },
                { 4, 1, "East", 7.1 },
                { 5, 1, "South", 5.4 },
                { 6, 1, "SouthWest", 2.9 },
                { 7, 1, "West", 6.8 },
                { 8, 1, "North", 3.3 },
                { 9, 1, "NorthWest", 5.7 },
                { 10, 1, "East", 4.9 }
            };

            // Вычисляем среднюю скорость ветра в январе
            double averageSpeed = calculateAverageWindSpeedInMonth(data, 1);

            // Проверяем, что средняя скорость вычислена правильно с точностью до 0.01
            Assert::AreEqual(5.26, averageSpeed, 0.01);
        }
    };
}
```

processing.h

```
#ifndef PROCESSING_H
#define PROCESSING_H

#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "book_subscription.h"

double calculateAverageWindSpeedInMonth(const std::vector<WindInfo>& data, int month);
std::vector<WindInfo> readDataFromFile(const std::string& filename);

#endif  // PROCESSING_H
```

book_subscription.h

```
#ifndef BOOK_SUBSCRIPTION_H
#define BOOK_SUBSCRIPTION_H

#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
struct WindInfo {
    int day;
    int month;
    string direction;
    double speed;
};

bool isWindInDirections(const WindInfo& windInfo);

bool isWindSpeedGreaterThan5(const WindInfo& windInfo);

void shakerSortBySpeed(std::vector<WindInfo>& data);

void mergeSortByDirection(std::vector<WindInfo>& data, int start, int end);

void merge(std::vector<WindInfo>& data, int start, int mid, int end);

#endif  // BOOK_SUBSCRIPTION_H
```

process.cpp

```
#include "processing.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

double calculateAverageWindSpeedInMonth(const std::vector<WindInfo>& data, int month) {
    double sum = 0.0;
    int count = 0;

    for (const WindInfo& wind : data) {
        if (wind.month == month) {
            sum += wind.speed;
            count++;
        }
    }

    if (count > 0) {
        return sum / count;
    }
    else {
        return 0.0;
    }
}

std::vector<WindInfo> readDataFromFile(const std::string& filename) {
    std::vector<WindInfo> data;
    std::ifstream file(filename);

    if (!file) {
        std::cerr << "Ошибка открытия файла: " << filename << std::endl;
        return data;
    }

    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(file, line)) {
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        WindInfo wind;

        if (!(iss >> wind.day >> wind.month >> wind.direction >> wind.speed)) {
            std::cerr << "Ошибка чтения данных из файла: " << filename << std::endl;
            return data;
        }

        data.push_back(wind);
    }

    return data;
}
```

data.txt

```
1 1 West 6.2
2 1 NorthWest 4.5
3 1 North 3.8
4 1 East 7.1
5 1 South 5.4
6 1 SouthWest 2.9
7 1 West 6.8
8 1 North 3.3
9 1 NorthWest 5.7
10 1 East 4.9
```

I haven't tried anything, I don't know how to fix it

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXpur.png)

Comment: Have you compiled `process.cpp`? Do you even have a `process.cpp` file?

Comment: process.cpp added to the question

Comment: Good, but is it compiled? It seems the linker can't find `process.obj` which is the output file you'd get when compiling `process.cpp`.

Comment: Do you mean compile to exe file? @TedLyngmo

Comment: In Visual Studio source files need to be added to the project for them to be compiled. If they are not part of the project they are ignored by the compiler. Open up "Solution Explorer" and verify that `process.cpp` is listed as part of the project.

Comment: What do you mean by compiling a file? I add screenshot my VS @TedLyngmo

Comment: This question teaches you how the build process works: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264249/how-does-the-compilation-linking-process-work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264249/how-does-the-compilation-linking-process-work)

Comment: @VovaLeksakov When you press the "Play" button, it will start compiling the files that belongs to the current project and all the `.cpp` files you need should be part of the project. I can't see what files you have in your project from that picture, but I'm guessing `process.cpp` isn't. When compiling all the `.cpp` files is done, it will link them into an `.exe`. That's the step that fails for you because `process.cpp` was never compiled - presumably because it's not in your project.

Comment: Looking at the picture `process.cpp` is not part of the unit-test-project. Its part of the `ConsoleApplication35` but that is an executable application and not a library so you can't link to this project.

Comment: @drescherjm Ah, it **was** there! Just had to scroll right a bit :-)

Comment: I was adding a link to the project, if I understood correctly. I added a screenshot. If I'm wrong, please tell me how to do it

Comment: My program runs well. But when I do unit testing it gives an error.

Comment: It gives you an error because the unit-test-project does not build or link the object file for process.cpp or any of the other cpp files in the  ConsoleApplication35 project.

Comment: I apologize for my ineptitude. Can you tell me how to do this?

Comment: You could make a library where your ConsoleApplication35 and unit-test-project depend on and that library contains project.cpp and all source files but main.cpp from that project. Or you right click on unit-test-project and add the project.cpp (and possibly other source files) to this project.